# Can I save the working status of Ubuntu before reboot, and recover it after reboot?

Tags: virtual-machine, suspend, reboot

Is it possible to save the working status of Ubuntu,and reboot it and recover its working status?  By working status of Ubuntu, I mean things such as the programs that are running, and the statuses of the individual processes.

Are the following ideas possible?

1. When I suspend Ubuntu, the working status of Ubuntu is saved to disk, and when I wake it up, the working status is recovered, i.e. I can resume what I left when suspend it. Can this be generalized to reboot?
2. Modern Operating Systems says:

   > With virtual machines now available, a software developer can carefully construct a virtual machine, load it with the required
   >   operating system, compilers, libraries, and application code, and
   >   freeze the entire unit, ready to run. **This virtual machine image**
   >   can then be put on a CD-ROM or a Website for customers to install or
   >   download. This approach means that only the software developer has
   >   to understand all the dependencies. The customers get a complete
   >   package that actually works, completely independent of which
   >   operating system they are running and which other software,
   >   packages, and libraries they have installed. These ‘‘shrink-
   >   wrapped’’ virtual machines are often called virtual appliances. As
   >   an example, Amazon’s EC2 cloud has many pre-packaged virtual
   >   appliances available for its clients, which it offers as convenient
   >   software services (‘‘Software as a Service’’).

   Does a "virtual machine image" save the working status of the OS (the programs that are running and     the statuses of the processes), or
   just the installed packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange question, but it seems there is a Russian project for that, at least for your own use. Not sure about it working well to give to customers. Can't recall the project name atm

Comment: What do you mean by generalized to reboot, shouldn't suspending satisfy your needs already? The virtual machine image includes all the non-volatile status of a virtual machine, it usually doesn't include the running status like memory data, registers value of CPU or other devices. But I believe some virtualization technology may offers you the function to snapshot the whole status of a virtual machine into an single image file and then let restore it later

Comment: Virtual box, I believe it  supports guest OS suspension, but I don't think the suspended virtual machine can be port to another host machine easily. While the virtual machine itself including all its hardware configuration and virtual disk images can be port to another host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know Ubuntu with Gnome hasn't got that feature. I don't know if other Desktop Environments (like KDE, Mate, Xfce) have the ability to re-open programs after reboot like Mac does (same programs, but different processes from previous usage). Personally I think that is an interesting feature but I know I would never use it.

Something similar is reachable if you use Virtual Box: you can install Ubuntu in a virtual machine and use the "save session" button instead of "shutdown". when you wake up the vm it starts from where you left, it's like a suspension on real hardware (same programs with same processes).
This behaviour is probably what you where looking for (if I understand you question correctly).

Comment: You're talking about a very high-level "save your session" functionality provided by DE. While OP's asking about suspension, which saves the whole physical memory.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 What are their differences?

Comment: Try it for a few days, you will see it can't restore your state. Your currently opened documents may not even be restored.

Comment: It simply re-open current apps, if the apps are not well coded for this, then it's just like a fresh open. Also this functionality never promise to you it will save the whole  system status, e.g.  daemons running out of the session

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 WHat does that functionality do to "daemons running out of the session "?

Comment: @Tim Nothing, this functionality doesn't touch them.